# Does Kotlin suspend funtion runs on a separate thread?

Tags: kotlin, coroutine, kotlinx.coroutines

suspend funtions run on a seperate thread ?
If not, then what is the performance benefit ?

```
suspend fun requestToken():Token {..}  // takes 2 sec to complete
suspend fun createPost (token:Token){..} // takes 3 sec to complete

 suspend fun postItem() {
    val token = requestToken()
    val post =createPost(token)
    processPost(post)
  }
```

So, when we reach at **processPost(post)** and if suspend function do not run on a seperate thread then we have to wait for **requestToken()** and **createPost(token)** method
 to complete **(i.e 2+3= 5 seconds)**. As per the author, suspend is asyncronous,but if we are not spawning any new thread then how are we achieving asychronous behaviour ?

Comment: You should read the [documentations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines-overview.html)

Answer (score 5):

> suspend is asynchronous

`suspend fun`s execute synchronously with their caller. What you actually meant to say is "non-blocking" and that's a completely different story.

> but if we are not spawning any new thread then how are we achieving asynchronous behaviour?

You are making the tacit assumption that all I/O must be blocking at some level. This is wrong. Non-blocking I/O works by pushing data to a send buffer and receiving notifications when there's data in the receive buffer. A `suspend fun` hooks into this mechanism by suspending itself after pushing the data to a send buffer and installing a callback that will resume it when response data is ready in the receive buffer.

Comment: If i want to make a network call  off the UI thread in **requestToken()** then do i have to create a separate worker thread or does this suspend function will automatically execute it in some background thread and control will move to the next line** createPost(token)** only after getting the result/token.
Thank You

Comment: I can only repeat what I stated in the answer: `requestToken()`, being a suspendable function, does not block the thread it's called on, nor any other background thread. You can simply call it on the UI thread. However, since `requestToken()` is just something you saw in the sample code, the key concern you should have is how to implement your own suspending functions. For that you can read [this section](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/coroutines.md#wrapping-callbacks) of the official documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Suspension-points can only be used within a coroutine context, for instance:

```
fun main() {
    delay(1000)
}
```

Would not work because `delay` is a suspending function and the compiler wouldn't know how to handle that without a coroutine. When you do have a coroutine it can use something called a dispatcher to control thread ownership. Suspending means that the thread is no longer used to execute that part of your program but its doing something else or going idle. The way it works is that you can have several coroutines working at the same time without having a thread for each, that thread can then execute parts of each coroutine up to a suspension point. Generally the idea is that you can view suspending functions as "generators" which have stages for producing a result.

```
suspend fun hello() {
    println("Hello")
    delay(1000) // suspend here, let someone else use the thread while we wait
    println("World")
    delay(1000) // suspend again, we can still use the thread while waiting
    println("done")
}
```

Everytime this is suspended it uses the thread to work on another function until that suspends and the delay expires, at that point this function will *eventually* resume execution up to the next suspension point or finish execution entirely.

This is different to blocking code as it does not waste the thread by putting it into **wait** state but rather borrows it to another function. That way no other threads need to be created to have concurrency as you can still work on multiple functions without true parallelism, instead it uses concurrent execution of parts of the functions.

Coroutines don't necessarily protect you from blocking, if you call `Thread.sleep(1000)` its still gonna be a blocking call. It is the responsibility of the programmer to use suspending equivalents to blocking functions in order to maximize effectiveness of this concept.

For more details, please read the [documentation](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines#documentation) as its very detailed and helpful.

Comment: In most cases the coroutine dispatcher doesn't do any scheduling. It only ensures the coroutine is dispatched to its associated execution module (for example, the GUI event loop or an ExecutorService). The execution module then decides how to schedule it.

Comment: Scheduling means planning the execution of tasks, thats exactly what the job of the so called dispatcher is. It plans where and when a task is to be executed while an ExecutorService is just a resource used to execute the task. The dispatcher is the one which decides how resources will be used, just like a scheduler.

Comment: Sure, you can look at it however you want, but the thing is actually called a _dispatcher_, and the reason the name fits is as explained. A coroutine dispatcher in most cases just does the dispatch and not the scheduling, and this is because coroutines are mainly for integrating with existing event loops or other kinds of task schedulers.

Answer (score -1):

Background single thread or multiple background threads of a thread pool can be explicitly declared and then used, for example by passing it as a parameter, let's call this parameter "scheduler". The really cool thing about it is that initially started from the main thread it's automatically switched to the scheduler thread to execute a particular task on it and virtual machine kind of suspended or interrupted at this place and the thing which is even cooler the main thread gets unblocked and can execute something else while there is the task in background.

As soon as the task is finished, virtual machine sort of gets back to the point where it was suspended or interrupted before and then it resumes its execution from that point but now by also having the result returned from the background thread of the scheduler, below is the code snippet:

```
private val backgroundThread = ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 15L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, LinkedBlockingQueue())

GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main, CoroutineStart.DEFAULT) {
    postItem(backgroundThread))
}

suspend fun CoroutineScope.postItem(scheduler: ThreadPoolExecutor): Boolean {
    val token = requestToken(scheduler)
    val post = createPost(token, scheduler)
    return processPost(post, scheduler)
}

private suspend fun CoroutineScope.requestToken(scheduler: ThreadPoolExecutor): String {
    val def: Deferred<String?> = async(scheduler.asCoroutineDispatcher(), CoroutineStart.DEFAULT) {
        val token = networkApi.requestToken()
    }

    return def.await() ?: ""
}

private suspend fun CoroutineScope.createPost(token: String, scheduler: ThreadPoolExecutor): String {
    val def: Deferred<String?> = async(scheduler.asCoroutineDispatcher(), CoroutineStart.DEFAULT) {
        val post = networkApi.createPost(token)
    }

    return def.await() ?: ""
}

private suspend fun CoroutineScope.processPost(post: String, scheduler: ThreadPoolExecutor): Boolean {
    val def: Deferred<Boolean?> = async(scheduler.asCoroutineDispatcher(), CoroutineStart.DEFAULT) {
        val result = networkApi.processPost(post)
    }

    return def.await() ?: false
}
```

Comment: `virtual machine kind of suspended or interrupted at this place`---there's no such magic involved, it's just plain bytecode. A `suspend fun` compiles into a method that returns when the coroutine gets suspended. It returns a special value which the calling code recognizes and knows it's not the real return value.

Comment: You do mention the "virtual machine", but it has nothing to do with the virtual machine level, it's just plain and simple Java bytecode.

Comment: I don't understand your point but I didn't state anything about virtual machine level either and how it's processed where, the post is not about it.

Comment: Yes, it's primarily vague, leaving it completely open as to the level at which this happens. I thought you might be interested in what actually goes on.

Comment: Please could you tell me what your point is? What you're trying to say by all your statements above and I suspect that you're the one who down voted my answer even if it practically shows how to run a coroutine on a background thread and your answer doesn't give any practical recommendation at all.

Comment: The downvote isn't mine. In my first comment I made a constructive remark that aimed to help your own understanding as well as to work as a clarification to any reader of your answer. Your engagement with my comment was strictly on the level of defending your wording.

Comment: Now that you bring attention to your code, I find it both wrong and misleading: 1. uses the anti-idiom of `async-await` without concurrency. 2. Wraps what is already a `suspend fun` into a senseless additional layer to get nothing more than another `suspend fun`. 3. Creates a `Dispatcher` each time it's called. The dispatcher should have been a top-level property instead of the raw executor. 4. Doesn't even compile.

Comment: Regarding your first comment, as you properly quoted it was "virtual machine kind of suspended or interrupted at this place". I have just intentionally double checked "kind of" meaning in Oxford dictionary so I recommend you to do the same to understand that all my wordings are correct from both lexical and technical points of view.

Comment: Regarding your comments to the code, only the last one is meaningful. It didn't compile because I copied/pasted it from the original question as well as tried to adapt the entire question's code snippet to execute it on a separate thread, that was the key point of the question and I answered it. Other comments don't have much sense.

Comment: I see. At this point my guess is that you misunderstand both the question and coroutines.  `requestToken` and others don't need another thread to avoid blocking the current one, they just _don't_ block any thread, which is the main point of suspension. The question is not how to make them block another thread, but how come they don't block it. OP asks for an explanation, not how to achieve something. Even if he did ask for it, the answer would have to be "you don't need it because `suspend fun`s don't block the thread.

Comment: I see too. You seem not to have read my answer carefully, just let me quote it really short to highlight the part you intentionally or unintentionally don't want see: "...and the thing which is even cooler the main thread gets unblocked and can execute something else while there is the task in background...". So just again you're making up something which I've never said but for some reason I am already not surprised.

Comment: If you do understand that your `CoroutineScope.requestToken` and others do not run on your `backgroundThread` --- because they don't run on _any_ thread and instead spend most of their life in suspension, then what is the point of your code example? What is the point of showing how to improperly use coroutines?

Comment: You're wrong, I have just executed my code snippet on my emulator, these are the log messages:

25774-26060/testapp D/TestApp: requestToken()
25774-26060/testapp D/TestApp: createPost()
25774-26060/testapp D/TestApp: processPost()
25774-25774/testapp D/TestApp: result = true

So as you can see requestToken() + createPost() + processPost() are executed on separate thread (tid = 26060) and result is eventually return on the main thread (tid = 25774)

Comment: Great work! You confirmed the obvious through experiment. The one microsecond of those functions' actual CPU work is spent on your thread. Now explain: what was the motivation to move that one microsecond to another thread? What real-life problem did it solve? Just the overhead of handing off work to your thread and back has a cost in the tens of microseconds---at best.

Comment: Thanks! First of all, you're wrong because you said that functions are not executed on background thread though they do execute on the separate thread. And second of all what makes you think that requestToken() and other functions take microseconds time? It's a classic use case in real life when a user signs-in to remote server and an application request token (e.g. access token), it's network operation, that's why I put it as networkApi.requestToken(). Is it clear now?

Comment: I guess it has become perfectly clear that you do not understand coroutines. While the network operation is in progress, the coroutine is not executing on any thread. When the operation is complete, the coroutine resumes on the thread that the dispatcher determines. In your case it will resume on `backgroundThread` to do nothing else but execute more thread coordination code to propagate that result back to the calling coroutine, which will then resume on the original thread.

Comment: I am very happy for you that you know a little basics of coroutines, keep it up. The point is that I have just proved you wrong as well as giving you a real life example how to use it and the subsequent discussion getting less interesting to me. Now I understand who I am talking to, please don't waste my time.

Comment: Time spent learning is not time wasted. Now, since this site is all about teaching others, would you please fix your answer so it doesn't mislead the reader?

Comment: The code sample works well, try it and see for yourself. All time-consuming operations are executed on a separate thread as it was asked by the original question and as you stated it wrong that it didn't but in fact it does. As to your comments (1, 2, 3) then I've already explained it, the most of them don't have much sense, it depends on requirements and design, you can't claim it as the only way, either way is OK. If you don't understand it then I can't help you.